# Terminology for orthogonal projections

Tags: terminology, hilbert-spaces

Let $H = X \oplus Y$ a Hilbert space. Then, the map $p(x + y) = x$ is called the orthogonal projection onto $X$  *along $Y$*.

Why is it necessary to mention *along $Y$*? Of course if a space has a decomposition into two subspaces $U,V$ with $U \cap V = \{0\}$ then the projection onto one of them is unique and there is no information gained by saying "along" such and such space.

Comment: The projection is orthogonal if and only if $Y=X^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $H = X\oplus Y$, then the projection onto $X$ is not well-defined without $Y$. The reason for this is that the splitting $H = X\oplus Y$ is not unique. That said, given $X$ there are many spaces $Y$ such that $H=X\oplus Y$.

For $H=\mathbb R^2$, $X=span\pmatrix{1\\0}$, $Y_t=span\pmatrix{t \\1}$, we have $H=X\oplus Y_t$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

The splitting of $z:=\pmatrix{1\\1}$ in vectors from $X$ and $Y_t$ is
$$
\pmatrix{1\\1} = (1-t)\pmatrix{1\\0} + \pmatrix{t\\1}.
$$
Here, the projection of $z$ onto $X$ along $Y_t$ is given by $(1-t)\pmatrix{1\\0}$, which clearly depends on $t$ and ultimatively on the choice of the subspace that is mentioned by 'along'.

Comment: But if the projection is orthogonal, isn't $Y=X^\bot$ unique?

Comment: Yes, orthogonal if and only if $Y=X^\perp$. The question was a bit unclear in this respect

Comment: Oh, but I wasn't sure whether the orthogonal complement was unique...

Comment: One minor remark: Your splitting of $z$ equals $(0,1)$ on the right hand side.

Comment: I find your answer enlightening. This is a great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you want to specify "along $Y$" is that you may have to deal with multiple orthogonal projections at the same time, and then it is useful to have a way to speak of different projections without too much fuss. For example, this occurs in the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process, where you have to iteratively take a projection along a one-dimensional subspace and its orthogonal complement at every step. It's purely a matter of using the most convenient notation for all cases.